# Qt's OpenGL samples complain about some errors and won't run

Tags: qt, opengl, configuration

I am trying to run the OpenGL examples in ubuntu 10.04. I bravely compiled the Qt code as follows and it went fantastic.

```
./configure -prefix /home/user/Software/qt-4.7.4-openGL-without-opengl-graphics -xplatform linux-g++-32  -little-endian -opensource -debug-and-release -fast -exceptions -accessibility -stl -no-qt3support -xmlpatterns -multimedia -audio-backend  -svg -webkit-debug -script -scripttools -declarative -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff  -make translations -make tools -make libs -opengl desktop -lglut
```

But then out of satisfaction I got from successful compilation I tried running the examples and some won't run. As a start the 2dpainting example quits after printing the following.

```
hijackWindow() context created for Window(0xbf8b0f2c) 1 
QGLPixelBuffer: Unable to find a context/format match - giving up.
QGLWindowSurface: Failed to create valid pixelbuffer, falling back 
QGLWindowSurface: Using plain widget as window surface QGLWindowSurface(0x8bf4990) 
hijackWindow() context created for Widget(0x8be5ab0) 2 
Vertex shader for simpleShaderProg (MainVertexShader & PositionOnlyVertexShader)  failed to compile
Fragment shader for simpleShaderProg (MainFragmentShader & ShockingPinkSrcFragmentShader) failed to compile
QGLShaderProgram: shader programs are not supported 
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

And box example does not even get compiled, giving the following error.

```
qtbox.cpp: In member function 'virtual void QtBox::paint(QPainter*, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*)':
qtbox.cpp:327: error: 'gluPerspective' was not declared in this scope
```

Could some one tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does your graphics card support pbuffers?  Does it support a shader pipeline?  Isn't gluPerspective a part of GLUT?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea if it is a part of GLUT. I believe it should be. since it is  (at lease it should be) openGL Function.I have a redeon HD 3450 as my vedio card. not sure if it supports any of those youve mentioned.

Comment: I was wrong it isn't GLUT, it's old OpenGL, that's why I hadn't seen it.  You will have to write a test program that queries if Qt can detect these card features.  On the second line of the program output it hints that although a context has been created, it lacks the features needed by the QGLPixelBuffer.  So you will have to look at the source code, see what it is requesting, and get it to print out what features it managed to get via the `QGLContext::format()` method once the context has been created.

Answer (score 2):

You have not linked to -lGL

> LIBS += -lGLU

and include the glu.h file in your code.

> include "GL/glu.h"

Answer (score 1):

GluPerspective is part of the GLU library, and not supported as of newer (3.x?) versions of OpenGL. An easy way to update the example is to write your own replacement, something like this:

```
#include <QtOpenGL>

void gluPerspective(double fovy,double aspect, double zNear, double zFar)
{
 // Start in projection mode.
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 double xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
 ymax = zNear * tan(fovy * M_PI / 360.0);
 ymin = -ymax;
 xmin = ymin * aspect;
 xmax = ymax * aspect;
 glFrustum(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zNear, zFar);
}
```

Comment: -1 for "not supported in newer version of OpenGL". This information is incorrect. All old functions (including immediate mode) are available in OpenGL compatibility profile even in OpenGL 4.2. See corresponding specifications from OpenGL website.

Comment: the deprecation model has them scheduled for removal, the -1 was undeserved, as it is not supported, it is deprecated